# Enable Xdebug in PHP project under debian:9-slim container

Tags: docker, debian, xdebug

Here is the Dockerfile for an existing project I'm working on. I'd like to activate Xdebug for the hosted Symfony project. The problem is I need pecl to install Xdebug but I don't know where/how to add it !

```
##
#  Base
##

FROM debian:9-slim as base

ENV TERM="xterm" \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" \
    TIMEZONE="Europe/Paris" \
    COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 \
    NODE_VERSION=8.12.0 \
    PHP_VERSION=7.2

# System depdendencies
RUN apt-get update --quiet && \
    apt-get install --quiet --no-install-recommends --yes \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        lsb-release \
        wget && \
    wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg && \
    echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list && \
    apt-get update --quiet && \
    apt-get install --quiet --no-install-recommends --yes \
        curl \
        git \
        nginx \
        php${PHP_VERSION} \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-apcu \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-curl \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-dom \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-fpm \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-gd \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-iconv \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-intl \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-mbstring \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-mysql \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-opcache \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-pdo \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-uuid \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-xml \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-simplexml \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-zip \
        supervisor \
        p7zip-full \
        tzdata \
        unzip \
        libxml2-dev \
        php${PHP_VERSION}-soap \
        vim && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
    mkdir /run/php && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && \
    echo "${TIMEZONE}" > /etc/timezone

# Composer

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --version=1.10.9 --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
    composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative && \
    composer clear-cache

# Yarn

RUN curl -L -o /tmp/nodejs.tar.gz https://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/node-v${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
    tar xfvz /tmp/nodejs.tar.gz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 && \
    rm -f /tmp/nodejs.tar.gz && \
    npm install yarn -g

COPY .docker/php.ini /etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/50-setting.ini
COPY .docker/php.ini /etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/conf.d/50-setting.ini
COPY .docker/pool.conf /etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
COPY .docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY .docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]

WORKDIR /app
```

I've tried to add this in the middle of the file :

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
```

But building process fails with no clue !

So I've added this at the end :

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
RUN pecl install \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

No errors, but Xdebug still not working (nothing in phpinfo) !

What's wrong ?

Comment: I don't use pecl from a lot of time... but I would like to try to help you... shouldn't you put something between "install" and "\" of the first line you're trying to add ("pecl install \")? Did you try to remove "pecl install \"?

Comment: nothing happend when first line is removed ! You said you don't use pecl, but when I google Xdebug it always installed with pecl, is there another method ?

Comment: I run "pecl install xdebug" in a container created from docker image "php:7.2-fpm". It was successfully installed, but, after you should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so" to php.ini . Did you do that?

Comment: How can use several docker images ? As you can see I'm using "debian:9-slim" and there is no pecl in there !

Comment: $ docker run -it --rm --name php7-test php:7.2-fpm /bin/bash
then:
$ pecl install xdebug
Now, you should have xdebug installed. Take a look to the notes at the end installation procedure.
This is a very docker base question. I suggest you to take a look to the dockerfile official documentation.